# Vue how to get value from sub component

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Here is my use case:

My main page have several sub-components that collect different input from user, finally I want to submit the whole page with all inputs collected. Therefore I want to retrieve the data from sub-component

One option is to use `store`, but my sub-components are super simple, just some forms, `store` seems too heavy...
Another option is that I can modify `prop`, although I know this is bad practice, but this approach looks just perfect....

Is it ok to modify `prop` if my logic is simple?(just collect inputs from user)Or I have to go for `Vuex` and `store`

Comment: Have your sub components `$emit` data up to the main page. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on excellent answers from Ifaruki and Andres Foronda, another, related option is the use of the `sync` modifier on the child component's prop.

Suppose the child component has a prop named `name`. In the parent component, you can use the `sync` modifier like this:

```
<Child :name.sync="childName"></Child>
```

Then, in the child component, when the value of the `name` prop should be updated, don't update it directly. Instead, emit an event that follows the naming convention for sync-able props, which is `update:nameOfProp`. So in our example, the child component would do this:

```
this.$emit('update:name', newName);
```

The benefit of the sync modifier is that we don't have to write an event handler function in the parent component--Vue does that for us and updates the variable that is bound to the prop automatically.

You can read more details about the `sync` modifier [in the official docs.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier)

Answer (score 1):

Retreiving data from sub component works with `$emit` here an exapmle:

```
//parent copmonent

<template>
   <div>
      <child @someEvent="someMethod"></child>
   </div>
</template>

import child from "path/"
<script>
export default {
   components: {
      child
   },
   methods: {
      someMethod(data){
         console.log(data);
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

Child component

```
<template>
   <div>
      <button @click="sendEvent">send</button>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   methods: {
      sendEvent(){
         this.$emit("someEvent", "working");
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

`$emit` takes 2 arguments. The first is the event name and the second one is the data that you send.
The parent just needs to listen with `@` for that event that being fired.

Answer (score 1):

you can listen an event from child an update the parent data property

```
//parent component
<div>
  <input-name @updateName="eventToUpdateName" /> <!--child component-->
</div>
...
data: () => ({ nameFromChild: '' )},
methods: {
  eventToUpdateName(value) {
    this.nameFromChild = value; // Update from child value emitted
  }
}
...
```

And in the child component

```
// Child component
<input v-model="name" />
...
data: () => ({ name: '' }),
// watch for changes in the name property and emit an event, and pass the value to the parent
watch: { name() { this.$emit('updateName', this.name } }
...
```

Also, You can use a v-model directive and emit 'input' event from child.

```
//parent component
<div>
  <input-name v-model="nameFromChild" /> <!--child component-->
</div>
...
data: () => ({ nameFromChild: '' )}
...
```

Now in the child component you can have

```
// Child component
<div>
  <input v-model="name" />
</div>
data: () => ({ name: '' }),
props: { value: { type: String, default: '' },
created() { this.name = this.value }, // You can receive a default value
watch: { name() { this.$emit('input', this.name } }
...
```