# How do I trigger a click event using eventBus on vue?

Tags: vue.js

New to Vue.js, trying to use the eventBus to emit events in different sibling components.

Here's the interaction I want to happen. 
 1. I click on a delete button on a card component.
 2. A modal pops up asking to confirm the deletion.
 3. User clicks OK in the modal to confirm deletion.
 4. That click emits an event to the card component that triggers its delete method, finally deleting it.

My code is fine all the way to step 3 and then it just conks out.

I've been trying to use the eventBus but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code starting from step 3.

```js
props: {
  jobs: { type: Array, default: null }
},

created(){
    bus.$on('confirmGigDelete', () => {
        console.log('running');
        // What do I do here?
    });
},

methods: {
    deleteMyJob(id) {
        console.log('this was deleted');
        fetch(`${API_URL}/${id}`, {
            method: "DELETE"
        });
    },
```

Is it possible to trigger confirmGigDelete this way in the HTML?

```js
<img
    :src="require('../../../assets/icons/common/deleteIcon.svg')"
    id="deleteButton"
    class="delete icon button"
    @confirmGigDelete="deleteMyJob(job._uid)"
    @click="showDeleteForm"
/>
```

Comment: why dont just use `this.$emit()`?

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate?

Comment: could you show us your parent component

Comment: Sure. Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/juanyeeast/pen/QWyKaVo)

Comment: EventBus is not recommended, so a better way is to build a container component, which wrapping all these components aforementioned, then use `emit` to emit specific events to parent, and dispatch children components' events to finish your work.

Comment: i have answered a similar question already, try this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61473174/vue-how-to-get-value-from-sub-component/61473518#61473518

Comment: I've refactored the code so the 2 sibling components communicate via emit and props through the parent component. I'm still stuck on this issue of how to trigger @confirmGigDelete so i can run "deleteMyJob(job._uid). What can I pass down from the parent to trigger confirmGigDelete?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using the event bus in Vue as it is stated in the official documentation about [dispatch and broadcast](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#dispatch-and-broadcast-replaced)

It's better to use the event system for communication between child and parent. The child emits an event with `this.$emit('event-name', payload)` and the parent listens for events from its child with `@event-name="myMethodInParent"`. This is just the good practice. The other good option is the use `Vuex` and to mutate state directly from child components.

[Vue events docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html)
[Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)

Comment: Oh ok. Good to know.  The issue is that the emit happens between 3 different components. Maybe I should just rephrase my question and ask how I could trigger that @confirmGigDelete="deleteMyJob(job._uid)"

Comment: You can use Vue events only in Vue components, so your `<img>` HTML element must be in .vue file and it must be the child component. ` @click="showDeleteForm"` your method `showDeleteForm` should emit the event `this.$emit('confirm-gig-delete', job.id)` and where you use the child component in the parent you use the listener <childComponent @confirm-gig-delete="deleteMyJob(job._uid)">